# Error while implementing matrix exponentiation

Tags: java, exponentiation

I tried to implement fast exponentiation using explanation from article on geeksforgeeks but it shows error while solving:
https://www.spoj.com/problems/FIBOSUM/

Can anyone explain what’s wrong with the code?
I tried by computing Fibonacci sum for last element of given range and Fibonacci sum of element before beginning of range and subtracted them, but it shows tle and incorrect answer.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;

class GFG {

    public static int fib(int n) {
        if(n<=1)
        return n;
        int f[][] = new int[][]{{1,1},{1,0}};
        int g = power(f,n-1);
        return g;

    }

    public static int power(int f[][],int n){
        int b[][] = new int[][]{{1,1},{1,0}};
        int sum = 1;
        for(int i = 2;i<=n;i++){
            multiply(f,b);
            sum = sum+f[0][0];
        }
        return((sum+1)%1000000007);
    }

    public static void multiply(int f[][],int b[][]){
        int x = f[0][0]*b[0][0]+f[0][1]*b[1][0];
        int y = f[0][0]*b[0][1]+f[0][1]*b[1][1];
        int z = f[1][0]*b[0][0]+f[1][1]*b[1][0];
        int w = f[1][0]*b[0][1]+f[1][1]*b[1][1];
        f[0][0] = x;
        f[0][1] = y;
        f[1][0] = z;
        f[1][1] = w;

    }
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = s.nextInt();
        for(int i = 1;i<=t;i++){
            int n = s.nextInt();
            int m = s.nextInt();
            if(n!=0)
                n = fib(n-1);
            m = fib(m);
           System.out.println((m-n)%1000000007);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to take care of negatives as (m-n+MOD)%MOD